# Is there any particular standards or name for documenting endpoints of your library?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, documentation

Every library,tutorial or framework documentation I saw online, have several pseudo-code syntax for accessing endpoints or functionality, but sometimes it doesnt make any sense.Is there any standard for that?

For example 
    chmod +x 
here filename is enclosed in **< >** these symbols but while writing command we ignore **<>** these, similarly mozilla developers guide have following syntax for javascript arrow functions.

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements } 
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
// equivalent to: => { return expression; }

// Parentheses are optional when there's only one parameter name:
(singleParam) => { statements }
singleParam => { statements }

// The parameter list for a function with no parameters should be written with a pair of parentheses.
() => { statements }
```

So is there any defined standards for such kind of generic documentations?

Answer (score 0):

There is [JSDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSDoc) specification which defines documentation syntax supported by most of the IDE (VisualStudio, WebStorm, NetBeans, etc.). Eclipse and Aptana support similar specification [ScriptDoc](https://github.com/aptana/sdocgen/wiki/Supported-ScriptDoc-Tags).

If a project use specific tool for documentation generation it must use syntax defined by that tool. Try to [Google them](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20documentation%20generator) so see more.

If the documentation is hand-written or the documentation is in code comments or  self-documented functions then there is no strict syntax, but most developers use the JSDoc since it's supported by IDEs.

Lots of similar specifications exist for other languages, for example [PHPDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc), and most of them are based on [JavaDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) developed by Sun for documenting Java classes and methods.